# Como instalar en xampp con php 7.2 el PDO_SQLSRV Driver de SQL Server 2017 en linux

Tags: sql-server-2017

¿Como se instala el driver sqlsrv de php en linux manualmente usando Xampp con ubuntu?

He descargado los drives de https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql

Pero no se donde colocar los archivos .so php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts.so en Xammp

Mi instalación de xammp esta en /opt/lampp

Nota:

Es evidente que si instalo php con apache de manera global es super fácil pero yo necesito que corra el driver de sqlsrv sobre Xampp.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No se puede cargar la librería pdo\_sqlsrv en php (xampp - ubuntu)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/240445/no-se-puede-cargar-la-librer%c3%ada-pdo-sqlsrv-en-php-xampp-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

acabo de realizar este procedimiento y te voy a compartir mi experiencia que tuve para poder ejecutar ese driver en los modulos de php con xampp, debo suponer que tienes instalado sql-server para seguir con los pasos.

*Lo primero que te voy a recomendar es hagas un backup de tus proyectos de php que están en HTDOCS y también hagas lo mismo con las bases de datos de mysql, esto lo recomiendo ya que vamos a instalar otra versión del XAMPP y puedas recuperar tus proyectos y bases de datos que tengas en el momento. Porque vamos a instalar la versión 7.3.2 de XAMPPl, si ya la tienes pues no es necesario que hagas este proceso si no, ejecuta este comando para des instalar xampp

```
sudo /opt/lampp/uninstall
```

Y luego elimina todo el directorio LAMP con el siguiente comando

```
sudo rm -r /opt/lampp
```

Cuando ejecutes esos 2 comandos y descargar la versión de XAMPP que te digo la versión [7.3.2](https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.3.2/xampp-linux-x64-7.3.2-0-installer.run). y ejecuta el programa con sudo

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.3.2-0-installer.run
```

y sigue los pasos del instalador, es importante que en la opción de componentes en el administrador tengas los 2 campos seleccionados como esta en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando finalices el proceso de instalación abre la consola y ejecuta los siguientes comandos para instalar los drivers con la herramienta pecl

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install sqlsrv
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

cuando finalice la descarga de cada uno, verifica que estén instalados y que versión tienen, en estos momentos y para mi caso se instalaron las siguientes versiones, ejecuta el siguiente comando

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl list
```

estas serian las versiones instaladas

```
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package    Version State
pdo_sqlsrv 5.6.0   stable
sqlsrv     5.6.0   stable
```

Lo siguiente es copiar las extensiones en el archivo php.ini y lo vamos hacer de la siguiente manera con los siguientes comandos

```
sudo echo "extension=sqlsrv.so" >> /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
sudo echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

Verifica que las extensiones en el archivo php.ini se copiaron correctamente con el siguiente comando

```
cat /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

deberías de ver algo así en la ultima linea del archivo:

```
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

Ahora vamos a mirar los módulos de php que están instalados con el siguiente comando:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php -m
```

en este punto es donde muestra el error de que no encuentra el fichero de la extensión como advertencia de PHP. saldría un error como el siguiente

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried:
>   /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlsrv.so
>   (/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found
>   (required by /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlsrv.so)),
>   /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731//opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731//opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown
>   on line 0

Ahora el truco para que funcione es el siguiente, cambiar el nombre del archivo que dice que no lo encuentra, con el siguiente comando

```
sudo mv /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6_old
```

ahora reinicia apache desde consola

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp reloadapache
```

Ahora vuelve a mirar los módulos instalados en php con el siguiente comando

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php -m
```

deberías ver los 2 módulos en el listado que son pdo_sqlsrv y sqlsrv.

por ultimo nos queda detener xampp y volverlo arrancar:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

ahora solo queda comprobar en un archivo php la información de phpinfo()

crea el archivo con la funcion phpinfo() y corre la ruta de ese archivo en el navegador y deberías de ver lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ojala te sirva!!.
Esto seria todo lo que debes hacer para que puedas usar sql server desde php con xampp en linux, saludos y que estés bien

Comment: Duplicado de _: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/240445/no-se-puede-cargar-la-librer%C3%ADa-pdo-sqlsrv-en-php-xampp-ubuntu/240792#240792

Comment: Para quien pase por acá: no se duplican las respuestas; se marca la pregunta como duplicado