# No se puede cargar la librería pdo_sqlsrv en php (xampp - ubuntu)

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, pdo, xampp, php7

quisiera saber si alguien a dado con la solución al problema de **PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library**

para ser exactos, estoy tratando de instalar los drivers de pdo_sqlsrv para la conexión desde php a la base de datos SQL-server, pero al mirar si tengo instalado el modulo en php, me sale este error

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so'
>   (tried:
>   /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so
>   (/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found
>   (required by
>   /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so)),
>   /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so
>   (/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown
>   on line 0

Estos son mis datos sobre la arquitectura que tengo
la versión de xampp instalada es la 7.3.2.0
la versión de php instalada es la 7.3.2
la version de pdo_sqlsrv instalada es la 5.6.0

Gracias por su tiempo, feliz día!!

Comment: acabo de dar solucion a este problema, por si alguien necesita la solución esta aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/240486/2770

Comment: Cristhian, si ya encontraste solución a tu problema, respondete a ti mismo la pregunta para que la cierres.

Comment: gracias @Mario  ,acabo de responderme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

acabo de realizar este procedimiento y te voy a compartir mi experiencia que tuve para poder ejecutar ese driver en los modulos de php con xampp, debo suponer que tienes instalado sql-server para seguir con los pasos.

*Lo primero que te voy a recomendar es hagas un backup de tus proyectos de php que están en HTDOCS y también hagas lo mismo con las bases de datos de mysql, esto lo recomiendo ya que vamos a instalar otra versión del XAMPP y puedas recuperar tus proyectos y bases de datos que tengas en el momento. Porque vamos a instalar la versión 7.3.2 de XAMPPl, si ya la tienes pues no es necesario que hagas este proceso si no, ejecuta este comando para des instalar xampp

```
sudo /opt/lampp/uninstall
```

Y luego elimina todo el directorio LAMP con el siguiente comando

```
sudo rm -r /opt/lampp
```

Cuando ejecutes esos 2 comandos y descargar la versión de XAMPP que te digo la versión [7.3.2](https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.3.2/xampp-linux-x64-7.3.2-0-installer.run). y ejecuta el programa con sudo

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.3.2-0-installer.run
```

y sigue los pasos del instalador, es importante que en la opción de componentes en el administrador tengas los 2 campos seleccionados como esta en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando finalices el proceso de instalación abre la consola y ejecuta los siguientes comandos para instalar los drivers con la herramienta pecl

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install sqlsrv
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

cuando finalice la descarga de cada uno, verifica que estén instalados y que versión tienen, en estos momentos y para mi caso se instalaron las siguientes versiones, ejecuta el siguiente comando

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl list
```

estas serian las versiones instaladas

```
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package    Version State
pdo_sqlsrv 5.6.0   stable
sqlsrv     5.6.0   stable
```

Lo siguiente es copiar las extensiones en el archivo php.ini y lo vamos hacer de la siguiente manera con los siguientes comandos

```
sudo echo "extension=sqlsrv.so" >> /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
sudo echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

Verifica que las extensiones en el archivo php.ini se copiaron correctamente con el siguiente comando

```
cat /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

deberías de ver algo así en la ultima linea del archivo:

```
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

Ahora vamos a mirar los módulos de php que están instalados con el siguiente comando:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php -m
```

en este punto es donde muestra el error de que no encuentra el fichero de la extensión como advertencia de PHP. saldría un error como el siguiente

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried:
>   /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlsrv.so
>   (/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found
>   (required by /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlsrv.so)),
>   /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731//opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731//opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown
>   on line 0

Ahora el truco para que funcione es el siguiente, cambiar el nombre del archivo que dice que no lo encuentra, con el siguiente comando

```
sudo mv /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6_old
```

ahora reinicia apache desde consola

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp reloadapache
```

Ahora vuelve a mirar los módulos instalados en php con el siguiente comando

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php -m
```

deberías ver los 2 módulos en el listado que son pdo_sqlsrv y sqlsrv.

por ultimo nos queda detener xampp y volverlo arrancar:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

ahora solo queda comprobar en un archivo php la información de phpinfo()

crea el archivo con la funcion phpinfo() y corre la ruta de ese archivo en el navegador y deberías de ver lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ojala te sirva!!.
Esto seria todo lo que debes hacer para que puedas usar sql server desde php con xampp en linux, saludos y que estés bien

Comment: Hola Cristhian, el sistema reporto esta publicación como un duplicado de esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/182365/como-instalar-en-xampp-con-php-7-2-el-pdo-sqlsrv-driver-de-sql-server-2017-en-li/240486#240486

Comment: @Jorgesys si es duplicado porque primero respondí la solución en una pregunta que no era mía, pero dime que hago, como buena practica para el sitio

Comment: @CristianMolina no te preocupes en realidad se agradecen tus contribuciones al sitio, pero te comento que el sistema señalo el duplicado, en este caso una de las respuestas no puede responder a la pregunta, en caso de que esto fuera así regularmente las preguntas son duplicados y podemos marcar los usuarios de la comunidad a cierre de la pregunta como duplicado.